# When I click on ImageButton click effect stays under other wigdet. (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, mobile

[image]

When I click on the menu, an effect occurs as in the picture. The resulting effect lags behind other objects. Either I have to reduce the diameter of this effect or the effect should be able to rise above other objects.
**how can i show the click effect better**

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawerScrimColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
      drawer: DrawerScreen(),
      backgroundColor: red,
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Builder(
          builder: (context) => IconButton(
            enableFeedback: false,
            focusColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
            icon: Image(
              height: 20.h,
              width: 20.w,
              image: AssetImage("assets/images/menu.png"),
            ),
            onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(),
          ),
        ),
        elevation: 0,
        shadowColor: Colors.red,
        backgroundColor: red,
        title: Text("deneme"),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      body: Column());
```

this is my code

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping IconButton with Padding.

Comment: I tried this before but it didn't work

Comment: Use stack widget and align the IconButton to TopRight and I think it should work 100%

Comment: It does't work :(

Comment: Can you send me your whole screen's code(Including body)?